# Eliminating URL in bbl file, and makebst

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I compiled my own bst file using the `latex makebst` command. This is a brilliant way of amending the style of references.

However, `makebst` creates a very ugly 'URL' prefix for web-pages. It just looks awful in a reference list.

How can I get rid of this ugly prefix? Thus far I amended the bbl file (I think it is line 5), but there must be a way of eliminating URL forever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
grep URL /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/custom-bib/*
```

reveals

```
 "\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL }"
```

so you just need to define `\urlprefix` to anything else (eg `{}`) then if it has a definition `\providecommand` does not redefine it.